# İf + Present "Using" for future?

Tags: present-tense, future-tense

İ have a question.

İf(when) his team is champion, he is happy.(he will (be) happy). > this can means for future?

Tnx

Comment: English Language Learners'a hoş geldiniz Mert! It is difficult for us to answer because you have many parentheses ( ) in the sentence. Are you asking only about the sentence: "If his team is champion, he is happy." ? If so, please edit your question :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking about a future-tense version.
`If his team become the champions, he will be happy.`

`When his team become the champions, he will be happy` has a different meaning.  `When` suggests they are expected to become champions.

Comment: If his team become the champions, he (is) happy. Can we use this for future. Witout a changes.  Tnx

Comment: No - his happiness is in the future if his team become the champions.